# Как точно перевести "Consumer Arbitration Service"?

Tags: переводы

Как правильно перевести на русский язык грамотно

> Consumer Arbitration Service

Эта фраза из соглашения с пользователем в магазине приложений для мобильного телефона App Store.

Я перевёл как:

> Пользовательский потребительский арбитраж

но фраза очень режет слух.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Пользовательский" и "потребительский" -  почти синонимы, поэтому вариант и не воспринимается. Термин "арбитраж" в русском привязан к арбитражным *судам*, в то время как Consumer arbitration решает споры между потребителем и поставщиком (товаров, услуг) в досудебном порядке:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_arbitration/
В русском не встречается буквального "потребительский арбитраж", но есть термин "**потребительские споры**", поэтому занимающуюся их разрешением (на основе соглашения поставщика с пользователем) службу можно обозначить так:

> Служба разрешения потребительских споров.

Comment: Спасибо, @Alex_ander !

Answer (score 0):

Consumer Arbitration Service

Возможный вариант перевода: **Пользовательский арбитражный сервис (служба)**

Consumer ―  потребительский, покупательский, Arbitration Service ―  арбитражный сервис

**АРБИТРАЖ**,  1. Специальный орган для разрешения имущественных споров между юридическими лицами (предприятиями и организациями); третейский суд. Ведомственный, государственный, международный  <**Арбитражный**,  А-ая комиссия. А-ые органы.

**СЕРВИС,**  Сфера обслуживания населения; совокупность учреждений по удовлетворению бытовых нужд и оказанию таких услуг. Служба сервиса. Гостиничный, автомобильный с.

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже так перевёл. Но понравился перевод ниже - _Служба разрешения потребительских споров._

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы зря отказались от слова "арбитраж": оно всем известно и не зря применяется  как юридический термин. Существительное "разрешение" неоднозначно по смыслу: оно что-то  разрешает (решает), а что-то разрешает (позволяет).

Comment: "Разрешение споров" - устойчивое юридическое понятие, см. напр. наименование статьи закона: http://www.electorat.info/encyclopedia/8714.html. Для носителя русского языка не имеет значения, является ли используемое в нём слово однозначным вне контекста:  в самом широком смысле третьей стороной споры именно "разрешаются", и такое выражение никогда не воспринимается как каламбур и т. п.

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант: **Арбитражная служба для пользователей**